# Bluetooth mouse stops working even though connected and paired on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

My new [Surface Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/surface/accessories/surface-mouse) randomly stops working. I'm running Windows 10 Creators Update, and more recently preview 16232. Both display the same behavior which is:

Mouse appears to work fine after it's first paired. Will work for a few hours then suddenly just stops working. Mouse still shows up as connected on the BT devices screens. If I turn the mouse on and off I disappears and reappears in the connected devices list (so there is clearly some communications) but the thing simply does not move the cursor.

If I try to remove/uninstall it by various means (Bluetooth and other devices settings, Device Manager etc.) typically I cannot repair the device and cannot get it to work. I even try to remove the batteries, turn BT on and off, start and stop the BT service, and restart the PC, yet nothing helps.

Having said that I have managed to get it reconnected 3 or 4 times since I've owned it, but I have no idea what combinations of things did the trick.

The "Add a device" screen, which looks like this, if I first remove and try to re-pair the mouse once it stops working:
[image]

Various settings showing Windows *thinks* the mouse is "Connected" yet its not actually working:
[image]

When using the [Bennett BT monitoring tool](http://www.the-sz.com/products/bennett/) I see this:
[image]
[image]